# Django Logging not working when deployed on Ubuntu/Apache Server

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, logging

My Django Logger works fine on my local machine but does not work when I deploy it to the server.

- Local: OS X 10.9.5, Python 2.7.5, Django 1.6.2
- Server: Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2.22, mod_wsgi Version: 3.3-4ubuntu0.1, Python 2.7.3, Django 1.6

On my local setup I run `python manage.py syncdb`, this creates the survey.log file which I then follow with `tail -f survey.log` so I can see the error messages as they are created.

On my server I run `python manage.py syncdb`, this creates the survey.log file which I then follow with `tail -f survey.log`. However I can not see any of my debug messages and when I inspect the file with `nano` it is empty.

Why is no logging data being recorded into `survey.log` on my production environment? What am I missing?

**views.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


logger.debug('This is your images list in 7: %s', images)
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'applogfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            #'filename': os.path.join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'survey.log'),
            'filename': 'survey.log',

            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*15, # 15MB
            'backupCount': 10,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'survey': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have now discovered that my Django error logs are getting written to my Apache error logs. Is this in any way normal?

Running

```
sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Provides me with the expected print out that I should be getting in my above Django error log file. e.g.

> ```
> [15/Dec/2014 21:36:07] DEBUG [survey:190] This is your images list in 7: ['P3D3.jpg', 'P1D1.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg']
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't using the correct logger in your views.py. Try this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('survey')
logger.debug('This is a debug message.')
```

The logger you get must match the loggers defined in `LOGGING`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Unfortunately it must not be the only problem as it is still not working. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: As slafs said, try using an absolute path for your logging file. The line of code you've commented out should work `os.path.join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'survey.log')`

Comment: Thanks, I also had to set write permissions on my survey.log file to get it working in the end

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the logfile actually gets created but in a directory that you don't except it to be. Try to put a full path in your configuration. Something like `'filename': '/tmp/survey.log',`, restart apache and check if it's there. Of course first you must apply a solution that Derek posted.

The reason you see the log message in your apache logs is probably because mod_wsgi configures somehow a default (`root`) logger and your configuration doesn't disable it (you have `'disable_existing_loggers': False,`).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't pass the full path of the filename, it is created in the directory  the running process is started ( or make a sys/chdir), it depends on the operating system which dir is used